# Set a mercurial username/email for one project?

Tags: mercurial

I can set my usual email address in my `~/.hgrc` file, but is there a way to specify that for one hg project I want to be known as a different name/email (similar to git's `.git/config` file in the project directory overriding the `~/.gitconfig` settings)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `<repo>/.hg/hgrc` file which will override settings in your `~/.hgrc`.

See `hg help config` for more details.